# android_alarm_manager plugin does not continue executing in background in Flutter:

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, background-process, dart-pub

I spent whole weekend in experimenting with [android_alarm_manager](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/android_alarm_manager) plug-in in flutter and finally got it working after firebase setup, **but not exactly**.

**Issue 1**: `AndroidAlarmManager.periodic` invokes in approximately `1 minute` regardless of duration what I set - (`5 secs`/ `15 secs`/ `30 Secs`).

**Issue 2**: Anyway it uses to run every minute in `foreground` (even if the device is `locked`), but doesn't work when in `background` (on `home` click). Though worked for couple of minutes when pressed `back` button.

Background running is what expected from this plugin. But I have no idea why it is behaving in this weird way. Any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if any of you facing the same issue or I am the only one.

**Steps Followed**:

1. *pubspec.yaml* - `android_alarm_manager`, `firebase_auth`, `google_sign_in`.
2. Addition of `google-services.json` and `com.google.gms.google-services` in both `build.gradle` files.
3. Addition of `service` tag in manifest file.
4. Creating `Application.java` class in src and addition of same (`.Appplication`) in manifest file.
5. [main.dart](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/android_alarm_manager/example/lib/main.dart) from [example](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/android_alarm_manager/example) file provided.
6. [reference](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/android_alarm_manager#-readme-tab-)

**main.dart -**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:isolate';


import 'package:android_alarm_manager/android_alarm_manager.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';


final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
FirebaseUser firebaseUser;


Future<void> ensureFirebaseUser() async {
  if (firebaseUser == null) {
    firebaseUser = await firebaseAuth.currentUser();
    if (firebaseUser == null) {
      firebaseUser = await firebaseAuth.signInAnonymously();
    }
  }
}


class HelloMessage {
  HelloMessage(this._now, this._msg, this._isolate, this._user, this._token);


  final DateTime _now;
  final String _msg;
  final int _isolate;
  final FirebaseUser _user;
  final String _token;


  @override
  String toString() {
    return "[$_now] $_msg "
        "isolate=$_isolate "
        "user='$_user' "
        "token=$_token";
  }
}


void printHelloMessage(String msg) {
  ensureFirebaseUser().then((_) {
    firebaseUser.getIdToken().then((String idToken) {
      print(HelloMessage(
        DateTime.now(),
        msg,
        Isolate.current.hashCode,
        firebaseUser,
        idToken,
      ));
    });
  });
}


void printHello() {
  printHelloMessage("Hello, world!");
}


void printGoodbye() {
  printHelloMessage("Goodbye, world!");
}


bool oneShotFired = false;


void printOneShot() {
  printHelloMessage("Hello, once!");
}


Future<void> main() async {
  final int helloAlarmID = 0;
  final int goodbyeAlarmID = 1;
  final int oneShotID = 2;


  // Start the AlarmManager service.
  await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();


  printHelloMessage("Hello, main()!");
  runApp(const Center(
      child: Text('Hello, world!', textDirection: TextDirection.ltr)));
  await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(
      const Duration(seconds: 5), helloAlarmID, printHello,
      wakeup: true);
  await AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(
      const Duration(seconds: 5), goodbyeAlarmID, printGoodbye);
  if (!oneShotFired) {
    await AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(
        const Duration(seconds: 5), oneShotID, printOneShot);
  }
}
```

**Console O/P** -

```
I/flutter ( 4893): [2018-11-26 01:27:56.093322] Hello, world! isolate=289040868 user='FirebaseUser({uid: .......
I/flutter ( 4893): [2018-11-26 01:27:56.120643] Goodbye, world! isolate=289040868 user='FirebaseUser({uid: .....
I/flutter ( 4893): [2018-11-26 01:27:56.123499] Hello, once! isolate=289040868 user='FirebaseUser({uid: ......
I/flutter ( 4893): [2018-11-26 01:28:57.860115] Hello, world! isolate=289040868 user='FirebaseUser({uid: ......
I/flutter ( 4893): [2018-11-26 01:30:00.037481] Hello, world! isolate=289040868 user='FirebaseUser({uid: .....
I/flutter ( 4893): [2018-11-26 01:31:08.422318] Hello, world! isolate=289040868 user='FirebaseUser({uid: .....
I/flutter ( 4893): [2018-11-26 01:32:08.545903] Hello, world! isolate=289040868 user='FirebaseUser({uid: .....
```

Though I still don't understand why `firebase` is being used with this plug-in, seems like I have done everything right btw. Thanks.

Comment: Please include some of the code within your question. Include the code that you think is important and relevant to your problem. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable question.

Comment: Hi @Ishaan appreciated your suggestion, but all the code that I used are exactly same from the example file that I've linked. So probably there is no reason to add it again here.

Comment: Yes, but it makes it much easier to see the code within the question in itself rather than have to switch tabs. Also, it is just generally recommended to do it across Stack Overflow, but its fine I guess.

Comment: Right bro, updated with some relevant info.

Comment: Don't you need to set `exact: true` to schedule something at an exact time?

Comment: @JonahWilliams addition of that makes the period of 1 minute more accurate, but custom duration like (5 secs/ 15 secs) still seems to be meaningless.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent). > Under normal system operation these alarms will not be dispatched more than once a minute.

Comment: Ok! Got it @JonahWilliams. Thanks for the reference, But flutter should have some plug-ins to run continuously in background. Otherwise services like whatsapp notifications when a new message arrives, will be quite hard to implement using flutter. Don't you agree?